# Class similarity coefficient for kNN

Tags: classification, clustering, k-nearest-neighbour, similarities

In our group we are dealing with misplacement of items and we came out with a method derived from knn, but we are not sure if there is already some place where this was described. The method would be this one:

*Let us imagine the situation where we have a group of items with different classes, lets say "red", "blue" and "green", situated in a Cartesian space. These items are located in some way closer one to another if they belong to the same class.*

*Now we introduce a new item with one of the three classes, lets say "red". Then we get the e.g. 10 nearest neighbors in the space and we get 6 red, 2 green and 2 blue. We would then assume this item has a score of 0.6 so probably its location is correct. However, if we had a red item with 2 red, 4 green and 4 blue this item would be probably misplaced since its score is 0.2*

We have been looking for references since this is not exactly knn clustering. Does anybody of you know if this approach was used before? If so, does the similarity measure have a name?

Thank you very much! I would also appreciate some input

Answer (score 0):

There is no kNN clustering. There is k-means, but that is unrelated.

What you are doing is kNN *classification* to check your labels for plausibility. Still, it's simple kNN classification by which you predict the expected label.